# Derivation of the tangent half angle identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry

> I'm having trouble proceeding from 
>   $$\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}$$
>   to
>   $$\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

Context:

> Consider the function $f$ defined for all $(x,y)$ such that $y \neq 0$, with the rule $$f(x,y) = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}$$
>   Show that $$f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)) = \tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$

So far I've done:
$$f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)) = \frac{r\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{r^2\cos^2(\theta) + r^2\sin^2(\theta)}+r\cos(\theta)} = \frac{r\sin(\theta)}{\sqrt{r^2}+r\cos(\theta)}\\=\frac{\sin(\theta)}{1+\cos(\theta)}$$

Using $$\cos(\theta) = 2\cos^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)-1 \implies 2\cos^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)=\cos(\theta)+1$$
We get $$f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)) = \frac{\sin(\theta)}{2\cos^2\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}$$
But I can't see how to proceed from here to the required result. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Hint:** The numerator can be written as
$$ \sin\theta = \sin \left(2 \cdot \frac{\theta}{2}\right) = 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}. $$

Comment: beautiful, thanks man! so quick too

Comment: Thank you for that, have a nice day!

Comment: In what sense is this answer a hint?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi In the sense that I did not solve the entire problem, I only showed how the OP can proceed to solve it by giving a hint.

Comment: All that's left to do is a division.

Comment: Well that's true. How else was I supposed to help then?

Comment: I guess one thing you could have done, if you wanted to be less direct, is say something like "Hint: try to express $\sin\theta$ in terms of $\sin\theta/2$ and/or $\cos\theta/2$" and just leave it at that.

Answer (score 12):

It is a lot easier to use some trig. identities: $\sin (\theta) =2 \sin (\theta /2) \cos (\theta /2)$ and $1+\cos \theta =2\cos ^{2} (\theta /2)$. You will immediately get the result from these two formulas.

Answer (score 9):

It's possible to understand many trigonometric identities with the [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).

Once you understand them, it's also much easier to remember them.

You can use two unit circles (one for $a$, one for $b$) to build a rhombus:

[image]

The sides of this rhombus have length 1.
From this diagram, you can see that:

$$\tan\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)}=\frac{\sin\left(a\right) + \sin\left(b\right)}{\cos\left(a\right)+\cos\left(b\right)}$$

In particular, with $a = 0$ and $b = \theta$, you have:

$$\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \frac{0 + \sin\left(\theta\right)}{1 + \cos\left(\theta\right)}$$

Comment: These function names (sin, cos, tan) should not be in italics.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I'm still learning Mathjax. Corrected, thanks!

Comment: This is a very helpful and useful diagram and I'll make use of it from now on when I'm stuck in long triple trig integrals haha, thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=\frac{\sin \theta}{1+\cos \theta}$ and $R=\tan(\theta/2)$.

## Left

\begin{align}
\frac{\textrm{d}L}{\textrm{d}\theta} &= \frac{\cos\theta(1+\cos\theta)-\sin\theta (-\sin\theta)}{(1+\cos \theta)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{1+\cos\theta}
\end{align}
Again
\begin{align}
\frac{\textrm{d}^2L}{\textrm{d}\theta^2} &= -(1+\cos\theta)^{-2}(-\sin\theta)\\
&=\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}\frac{1}{1+\cos\theta}\\
&=L\frac{\textrm{d}L}{\textrm{d}\theta} 
\end{align}

## Right

\begin{align}
\frac{\textrm{d}R}{\textrm{d}\theta} &= \frac{\sec^2(\theta/2)}{2}\\
&= \frac{1+\tan^2(\theta/2)}{2}\\
2\frac{\textrm{d}R}{\textrm{d}\theta} &= 1+R^2
\end{align}

Again

\begin{align}
2\frac{\textrm{d}^2R}{\textrm{d}\theta^2} &= 2R\frac{\textrm{d}R}{\textrm{d}\theta}\\
\frac{\textrm{d}^2R}{\textrm{d}\theta^2} &= R\frac{\textrm{d}R}{\textrm{d}\theta}
\end{align}

## Conclusion

\begin{align}
L&=R\\
\frac{\sin \theta}{1+\cos \theta}&=\tan(\theta/2)
\end{align}

## Edit

Assume that the questioner and his friend were asked to solve a differential equation $y''=yy'$ with $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1/2$.

Making the story short, he and his friend found the solution, $y=\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$ and $y=\tan(\theta/2)$, respectively.

He now can proceed from $\frac{\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta}$ to $\tan(\theta/2)$
without doubt.

Comment: Well not the answer to my question but useful regardless, I'll accept it